# Unsolved reference error in copyOfRange

Tags: kotlin

I'm trying to copy first 2 elements of my firstArray to my secondArray.

```
var firstArray = arrayListOf(1,2,3,4)

var secondArray = firstArray.copyOfRange(0,1)
```

However I'm getting "unsolved reference" error in copyOfRange for some reason.

If I define an Array type for my firstArray I can solve the problem but I don't want to because it can contain different variables in future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `arrayListOf` function returns an `ArrayList`. If this is what you want to use, then you should use the [`subList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#subList(int,%20int)) function on it:

```
val firstList = arrayListOf(1, 2, 3, 4)
val secondList = firstList.subList(0, 1)
```

Note that `subList` doesn't create a copy, you can make a copy with a `toList` call, for example:

```
val secondList = firstList.subList(0, 1).toList()
```

Or with an explicit call to the `ArrayList` constructor:

```
val secondList = ArrayList(firstArray.subList(0,1))
```

---

If you want to use an `Array` instead, use [`arrayOf`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/array-of.html) and then you can use [`copyOfRange`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/copy-of-range.html):

```
val firstArray = arrayOf(1, 2, 3, 4)
val secondArray = firstArray.copyOfRange(0, 1)
```